# How to define function in .emacs?

Tags: emacs

I define one function in my .emacs, I want to  activate ECB and goto to directory when I enter f12, but it does not work

```
(defun my-toggle-ecb ()
   (ecb-activate)
   (ecb-goto-window-directories)
  )

(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'my-toggle-ecb)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yea, that's one of Emacs' odder quirks. Unless you declare that a function is interactive, there's no way way to call it directly. Luckily it's easy:

```
(defun my-toggle-ecb ()
  (interactive)
  (ecb-activate)
  (ecb-goto-window-directories))
```

Your keybinding remains the same. Have fun!

Comment: why: See `C-h f interactive RET` for more details, and how `interactive` is used to obtain arguments from the user (or otherwise).